# Python - Check if a string contains multiple words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering if there was a function in Python 2.7 that checks to see if a string contains multiple words (as in words with spaces/punctuation marks between them), similar to how `.isalpha()` checks to see if a string contains only letters?

For example, if something along the lines of this exists...

```
var_1 = "Two Words"

if var_1.containsmultiplewords():
print "Yes"
```

And then "Yes" would be the output.

Thanks!

Comment: just split and check len it will be basic solution

Comment: Use a tokenizer if you want to do it properly. For example, you can use [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Basic implementation

Generally, you use `split()` to split a string of words into a list of them. If the list has more than one element, it's `True` (i.e. you could print *yes*)

```
def contains_multiple_words(s):
  return len(s.split()) > 1
```

#### Punctuation support

To support punctuation etc as well, you can split on a regular expression, via the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)'s split command:

```
import re

def contains_multiple_words(s):
  return len(re.compile('\W').split(s)) > 1
```

The regular expression *character class* `\W` means any single **non**-word character, e.g. punctuation or spaces (see the [Python regex syntax guide](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for details).

Thus, splitting on this instead of just space (the default in the first example) allows for a more realistic idea of "words".

Comment: Thanks @declension , managed to use `if len(var_1.split()) > 1:` to print what I wanted. Do you mind explaining what your punctuation section of code does, I'm fairly new to Python and still a bit shakey with modules?

Comment: No problem - updated above

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

No there don't exsist any mechanism of the shelf like this.

If your only aim is to find if it's only one word or there exsit another word it can be done by :

```
x = 'has words'
' ' in x
>>> True
```

Comment: ...this fails with trailing or leading spaces: `' ' in '   one' == True`